# Cordova error when running browser platform

Tags: cordova

I need help for a problem when I try to run cordova application with browser platform.

I get this error :

> c:\www\mobile-front-web-platform>cordova run browser Running command:
>   cmd "/s /c
>   "c:\www\mobile-front-web-platform\platforms\browser\cordova\build.bat""
>   Cleaning Browser project Running command: cmd "/s /c
>   "c:\www\mobile-front-web-platform\platforms\browser\cordova\run.bat
>   --nobuild"" Static file server running @ http://localhost:8000/app/out/index.html CTRL + C to shut down Error
>   executing "cmd /c start "" chrome
>   --user-data-dir=%TEMP%\temp_chrome_user_data_dir_for_cordova http://localhost:8000/app/out/index.html":

And when I execute cordova requirements I obtain this error :

> c:\www\mobile-front-web-platform>cordova requirements
>
> Requirements check results for browser: Check failed for browser due
>   to Failed to check requirements for browser platform. check_reqs
>   module is missing for platform. Skipping it... Error: Some of
>   requirements check failed

Comment: did you add browser platform - cordova platform add browser

Comment: Unfortunately yes :(

Error: Platform browser already added.

Answer (score 2):

I have found an answer here https://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/09/24/browser-as-a-platform-for-your-phonegapcordova-apps/

So, remove browser platform with

> cordova platform remove browser --save

And then

> cordova platform add browser --usegit.

And put chrome to your path variable system (if you are on Windows),
when I ran cordova requirements it still fails but the app runs with

> cordova run browser